# thread exception occurred in gevent

Tags: gevent

When I run the code below, a long time will appear this kind of error.

code:

```
from gevent import monkey; monkey.patch_all()
from gevent.pywsgi import WSGIServer 
sys.modules.pop("threading", None)
```

Exception info:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/greenlet.py", line 375, in _notify_links
    link(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gevent/threading.py", line 22, in _cleanup
    __threading__._active.pop(id(g))
KeyError: 40406544
(<function _cleanup at 0x1fed0c8>, <Greenlet at 0x2688e10>) failed with KeyError
```